# what exactly is AppCompatPreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android-studio, abstract-class

I have no idea of programming. I would like a very  informative  answer so i can fully understand what this class is about. I found this"implements and proxies the necessary calls
 * to be used with AppCompat." 
But i don't no either what is AppCompat.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

**PreferenceActivity :**

- It is the base class for an activity to show a hieracrchy of preferences to the user.
- *Example : To enable / disable notification , data sync frequency, etc.,*

**AppCompatActivity :**

- It is the base class for activities that use the support library for action bar features.
- You can add an ActionBar to your Activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending this class for your activity and setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompact or a similar theme.
- *Example: Provides Material color themes, widget tinting, appbar support, etc.,*

**AppCompatPreferenceActivity :**

- It is an abstract class, which extends PreferenceActivity.
- When you create a new preference activity from the menu, android studio itself add this class.
- *Example : Create SettingActivity from menu, it will extend from AppCompatPreferenceActivity.*
- This class has more useful methods (inflate, set / get support actionbar etc).
- *Example :To add the toolbar, inflate the toolbar and set it. Only minimal lines of code .*

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, that really helped!

Comment: Happy to help. Welcome:)